# "Manager" classes to store objects in oop

Tags: c++, oop

I recently read an article about how bad manager classes are because they can break oop concepts and for the most part I agree with the article besides in one point.
What if I create a manager class for simply storing my objects. E.g. if I create a bunch of "file" - objects they have to be stored in a "file cabinet" - object which would represent my "manager" in this case. Other objects (e.g. "employee") can get files out of the cabinet and read them (whereas the read() method would be implemented in the file-class and most likely be named "presentToViewer").

So in this example I would have a manager that stores some files and the employee can get the files from the manager. The manager has no additional function besides storing the objects. Is this bad design? If so, how should I store my files if not in such a manner and why is it bad design? Files have to be stored somewhere and if I don't implement a getFile() method in the manager, I could never get a stored file (although I read and understand that getters/setters are also not a good design pattern in most cases) and interact with it (e.g. call presentToViewer()).

Another example:
If this is not a good pattern, how should I implement the following code (in the Employee class and in c++, where "my_signature_" is the employees unique signature):

```
void Employee::writeDownClientBillNum(FileCabinet& file_cabinet,
                                      unsigned int client_id,
                                      unsigned int client_bill_num) const
{
  File& bill_file = file_cabinet.takeClientFile(client_id);
  bill_file.appendToBill(client_bill_num, my_signature_);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily bad, but calling this class a "manager" is a mistake, in my opinion. I'd rather call it a "resource cache" (if it's purpose is to cache resources so they don't have to be repeatedly loaded). Or a `std::vector` (or some other type of container object). I don't see why this class of yours needs to be a "manager" at all. It's not "managing" anything.

Comment: Manager Class is already a design problem, because you can not give them a name which tells what the manager do. In your case you have a cache or storage class. Sounds like glue class, god class. And yes, in OOP each class should abstract the underlying things. You manager did nothing as storing which is not a real abstraction. Your code snipped shows a lot of parameters which is typically a hint to bad design. Where are the objects and what is the responsibility of them when you need so much unbound values there?

Comment: @Cornstalks well, it is managing the lifetime of the Files if it stores them. I could have also referred to the class as "FileStorage" or something else but the question is actually not about the name itself (I named it FileCabinet) but whether this is valid design since the class reflects that what is often described in blog posts a bad manager/handler/etc class. What if I had only one FileCabinet in my office? A singleton class is also not really something that is considered as good design (at least from what I've read). So I guess what I'm actually asking is: how else should I store files?

Comment: @Klaus: Ok I see, thanks! So in the case that the client_id and the client_bill_num belong to a Client - object, how would you manage to write the clients bill to a file if the client has not access to the cabinet (he is not allowed to go into the office) (the code i posted is not part of any real program)

Comment: @CE70: The bill itself has a bill id and is directly related to a client. So these information should not be represented by two separated variables. If the client has to write to a file, he must have access to a function which do the job. For writing data to files take a look for serialization pattern/libraries like boost::serialize. But all what I mention is sen from my helicopter perspective of your design problem. Maybe I am wrong. See it as a hint not as a rule ;)